# Coldfusion 9: Round to 2 decimals on avg() in QoQ

Tags: coldfusion, rounding, qoq

Is there a way to round to 2 decimals in a query-of-query on an avg statement? I could not find a system function in the adobe docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in QoQ, no. The full docs for QoQ are here: "[Query of Queries user guide](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldusionlatest/Query+of+Queries+user+guide)". That includes the entirety of QoQ's functionality.

You're just gonna have to do the rounding when you're using the recordset.

It might be worth raising a ticket on the bug tracker to get an enhancement for this: https://bugbase.adobe.com/. It's functionality I've needed in the past.

Comment: Thanks, will open a feature request for it, seems like a logical addition for future versions.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do a similar thing to use the QoQ result in a chart.  I ended up using the QuerySetCell to format the QoQ column.

In the example code below, qryResult was my QoQ query name and MWDPCT was the column that I wanted to reformat.

```
<cfloop query="qryResult">
  <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(qryResult,"MWDPCT", decimalFormat(qryResult.MWDPCT),currentrow)>
</cfloop>
```

Hope that helps a bit.